# How to improve search performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains two `bigint` columns: `beginNumber`, `endNumber`, defined as `UNIQUE`. The `ID` is the `Primary Key`.

```
ID | beginNumber | endNumber | Name | Criteria
```

The second table contains a number. I want to retrieve the record from table1 when the Number from table2 is found to be between any two numbers. The is the query:

```
select distinct t1.Name, t1.Country
from t1
where t2.Number
BETWEEN t1.beginIpNum AND t1.endNumber
```

The query is taking too much time as I have so many records. I don't have experience in DB. But, I read that indexing the table will improve the search so MySQL does not have to pass through every row searching about m Number and this can be done by, for example, having `UNIQE` values. I made the `beginNumber` & `endNumber` in table1 as UNIQUE. Is this all what I can do ? Is there any possible way to improve the time ? Please, provide detailed answers.

EDIT:

table1:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `beginNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Criteria` varchar(455) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `beginNumber_UNIQUE` (`beginNumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `endNumber_UNIQUE` (`endNumber `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=327 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table2:

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id2`),
  UNIQUE KEY ` description _UNIQUE` (`description `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is a toy example of the tables but it shows the concerned part.

Comment: Please add a 'show create table' output for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an index on `t2.Number` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD INDEX numindex(Number);
```

Your query won't work as written because it won't know which t2 to use.  Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name, t1.Criteria
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.Number BETWEEN t1.beginNumber AND t1.endNumber);
```

Without the t2.Number index EXPLAIN gives this query plan:

```
1   PRIMARY t1  ALL                 1   Using where; Using temporary
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t2  ALL                 1   Using where
```

With an index on t2.Number, you get this plan:

```
PRIMARY t1  ALL                 1   Using where; Using temporary
DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t2  index   numindex    numindex    9       1   Using where; Using index
```

The important part to understand is that an `ALL` comparison is slower than an `index` comparison.

Comment: A query for 100 records takes over than 7 sec. is this normal? I have so many records, this is not efficient for me?

Comment: @user1810868: the issue is that you are comparing tables that don't have a direct relationship so you can't efficiently filtre out rows by joining the tables.  Your join would be something like `t1 JOIN t2 ON (t2.Number BETWEEN t1.beginNumber AND t1.endNumber)`. If you have the query cache turned on, creating a VIEW based on the query might help.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good place to use binary tree index (default is hashmap). Btree indexes are best when you often sort or use between on column.

CREATE INDEX index_name

ON table_name (column_name)

USING BTREE

Comment: but which column? Is it: beginNumber in col1 ??

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The only index type allowed (therefore it is the default) on InnoDB is BTREE.

Comment: @user1810868 the column on which you are searching - t2.Number.